# Not able to compile the app with SDWEBIMAGE

Tags: ios, iphone, sdwebimage

When I try to run the app I am getting the following error

```
d: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/btmani/Desktop/MyProject/download-indicato,twitter,imageview/sewebimageview/SDWebImage-progressbar-master/Examples/../../SDWebImage-3.3.framework/Versions/A'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ProgressBarInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DetailViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is really creating big problem to me, and I don't know how to fix it. Please suggest me how to fix this

Thanks in advance

Comment: It said, Directory Not Found.

Comment: This error is caused because your `DetailViewController` class is referencing another class, `ProgressBarInfo`, which doesn't exist. Based on some googling, it looks like `ProgressBarInfo` was added in [this fork of SDWebImage](https://github.com/kozze89/SDWebImage-progressbar) and perhaps you're using [the regular version](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)?

Comment: so how to fix this any idea. I need progress bar in my app when loading the image

Comment: Thanks for your response I have fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

This is a framework problem so please import ImageIO.framework. Clean your project and run it again.

if you are using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) then Update your SDWebImage framework .There are some important bug fixes for iOS 7 otherwise No Tension.